# $\binom{n}{0}.\binom{m}{k}+ \binom{n}{1}.\binom{m}{k-1}+...+\binom{n}{k}.\binom{m}{0}=\binom{n+m}{k} $

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have to prove this:

$$\binom{n}{0}.\binom{m}{k}+ \binom{n}{1}.\binom{m}{k-1}+...+\binom{n}{k}.\binom{m}{0}=\binom{n+m}{k} $$
I don't know how I can prove that. I tried to use the definition or Newton Binom but I can't prove

Comment: You have $n$ pencils and $m$ pens on a table and you want to choose $k$ of them. How many ways can you do this?

Comment: Note that the lower numbers always sum up to $k$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/337923/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91457/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1742596/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/787440/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7B0%7D.%5Cbinom%7Bm%7D%7Bk%7D%2B%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7B1%7D.%5Cbinom%7Bm%7D%7Bk-1%7D%2B...%2B%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D.%5Cbinom%7Bm%7D%7B0%7D%3D%5Cbinom%7Bn%2Bm%7D%7Bk%7D%24)